# Good tools to get all resources for a particular URL?

Tags: tools, resources

I'm looking for clues on which tool to use to see all the resources that a browser would load when going to a particular URL. This would be similar to the list seen in Chrome's Developer Tools -> Frames, but output as something nice like JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By asking on another site, I found out that Chrome's View -> Developer -> Developer Tools -> Network panel lets you save this information by right-clicking on the bottom bit which tell you all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug. It is an excellent add-on.
Don't forget to check the details here: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere in Firebug (or the FAQ, or the wiki) that allows for saving the results from a page. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You want [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for FireFox.   As you load a website it list every URL that is loaded along with the request and response headers that are sent and received.  There is a "save" button that you can use to save them all to disk.

Comment: This looks OK. I can save a text file and then pull out all the URLs after each line of dashes. I was hoping for something more complete (like Firebug, but savable...)